# I am getting table data from database and displaying on table but datatables search is not working on data

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatables and search field is not working on the data retrieved from database via ajax POST method. Kindly help me

I am unable to understand server processing documentation of datatables.

I am just simply taking data from database and appending it to  tag. I know i am doing wrong. I need help!

```html
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from program");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pid=(int)$row['ID'];
    $title=$row['TITLE'];
    $total=0;
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn,"select SUM(DISTINCT(TOTAL)) AS TOTAL from teams GROUP BY TEAM,PID having PID = $pid");
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    { 
        $total=$total+(int)$row1['TOTAL'];
    }
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from shows where PID = $pid");
    $start="";
    $end="";
    $i=0;
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        if($i==0){
            $start=$row2['START'];
            $i++;
        }
       $end=$row2['END'];
        $city=$row2['CITY'];
       }
    $arr[] = array("title" => $title,
                    "total" => $total,
                    "start" => $start,
                    "end" => $end,
                    "city" => $city,
                "pid"=>$pid);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datatable").DataTable()
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getPrograms.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(res) {

    $("#allPrograms").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      $("#allPrograms").append('<tr><td>' + res[i].title + '</td><td>' + res[i].total + '</td><td>' + res[i].start + '</td><td>' + res[i].end + '</td> <td>' + res[i].city + '</td> <td><span class="badge badge-secondary font-10">Active</span></td>' +
        '<td><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnAction" value="' + res[i].pid + '"><i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline" style="color:white"></i></button></td></tr>')
    }
  }).fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>Program Name</th>
      <th>Consultants</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="allPrograms"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your datatable after you have filled the html in page. i.e. Call this line `$("#datatable").DataTable()` after you re done inserting HTML on page.

On a separate note, dont use append to add HTML. This is a bad practice. Instead take a variable and append all the HTML in it. Once you are done, make a single call like `$("#allPrograms").html(yourVariableHere)` to insert the HTML on page.